# Can't reload our TFS analysis cube due to snapshot isolation

Tags: tfs, ssas

We're trying to reload the TFS 2010 SSAS cube, but when the warehouse is processing, we get an exception in the log.  It is important to note that the cube does not fail completely, but loads incompletely.  For example, we have data up to June 2011, but not beyond.

> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WarehouseException: OLE DB error: OLE
>   DB or ODBC error: Snapshot isolation transaction failed in database
>   'Tfs_Warehouse' because the object accessed by the statement has been
>   modified by a DDL statement in another concurrent transaction since
>   the start of this transaction. It is disallowed because the metadata
>   is not versioned. A concurrent update to metadata can lead to
>   inconsistency if mixed with snapshot isolation.; 42000

This is our future production system, and contains data migrated over from a TFS 2008 system.  The database size of the version control repository is close to 200GB, so we're dealing with a relatively large instance of TFS.

We could remove snapshot isolation from our warehouse, but I'm a little concerned about doing this, as I can't find anything that tells me whether snapshot isolation is required on the TFS_Warehouse database.   Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From [this source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dstfs/archive/2009/02/20/tfs-performance-tips-tricks-part-one.aspx) (see the **TempDB and RCSI** section), it would seem that removing snapshot isolation could be a big mistake.

Here are some other options ordered easy to difficult from and implementation standpoint...

1. increase the size of TempDB to accomodate longer running SELECTs
2. decrease the partition size the measure groups in the cube.  You may
   want to run a profiler trace durring SSAS processing first to
   determine which measure groups are taking the longest and chop those
   partitions up first
3. implement an incremental processing strategy

[Here's a link providing more information on cube-partitioning](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3843796/article.htm)...

Comment: Unfortunately for our first load after conversion, I don't think we can do #3.  Do you have any pointers for where I can learn about how to do #2?  Thanks!

Comment: gotcha...just added a link that provides info on cube-partitioning.